# python проблема с массивом

Tags: python, массивы

Добрый день,
Как сделать так,чтобы в массиве user подмассивов было столько сколько в data значений?
К примеру если у data 2 значения

```
user = [{'id':data[0],'email':data[1]},{'id':data[0],'email':data[1]}]
```

У меня получилось вот что

```
data=[['sad','sdada'],['sqewad','sdadewa'],['sakjjk','hghfada']]
r=len(data)
i=0
while i < r:
    user[i] = [data[i][0],data[i][1]]
    i = i + 1
```

Правильно ли я решаю задачу?
В чем ошибка кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка как минимум в том, что отступы в Python критичны. Вы объявляете цикл `while` без тела. Кроме того, здесь уместнее использовать цикл `for`, а не `while`. Также, одним из недостатков Вашего кода является то, что Вам нужно сначала определить размер массива.

Вашу задачу можно решить проще, если воспользоваться конструктором списков:

```
In [1]: data=[['sad','sdada'],['sqewad','sdadewa'],['sakjjk','hghfada']]

In [2]: user = [{'id': u[0], 'email': u[1]} for u in data]

In [3]: user
Out[3]: 
[{'email': 'sdada', 'id': 'sad'},
 {'email': 'sdadewa', 'id': 'sqewad'},
 {'email': 'hghfada', 'id': 'sakjjk'}]
```

Или функцией `map` (в Python 3 возвращает итератор, поэтому обернута в `list`):

```
In [4]: user = list(map(lambda u: {'id': u[0], 'email': u[1]}, data))

In [5]: user
Out[5]: 
[{'email': 'sdada', 'id': 'sad'},
 {'email': 'sdadewa', 'id': 'sqewad'},
 {'email': 'hghfada', 'id': 'sakjjk'}]
```

Comment: На счет отступов ,у меня они есть просто в so неправильно добавил.Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Egor2010 Для читаемости, можно имена использовать вместо индексов: `user = [dict(id=id, email=email) for id, email in data]`

Comment: `map` здесь не нужно использовать. Она менее читаема и менее производительна чем явное выражение со списком.